# Heteroscedasticity and Serial correlation test

Tags: regression, econometrics, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

Let’s consider linear regression model, estimated using OLS.

According to information from Hayashi (Econometrics, Chapter 2)

- it must be the case of no serial correlation in errors to perform White’s test for conditional heteroskedasticity;
- it must be the case of conditional homoskedasticity to perform both Ljung-Box Q test and Breusch-Godfrey test for absence of serial correlation.

Reasonable question arises: how someone should perform these kind of tests if H0 in one test is assumption in the other?

Maybe there exists some other tests, for example, for testing serial correlation that doesn’t rely on conditional homoskedasticity assumption or for testing conditional heteroskedasticity that doesn’t rely on no serial correlation assumption?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case for these tests? What kind of data do you have?

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty No specific data for now, just theoretical research.